# Backup a database using an sql query with datetime format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
string query = "BACKUP DATABASE DbName TO DISK = 'C:\\app\\dbName.Bak' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'dbName', NAME = 'Full Backup of dbName';";
```

This is the query I'm using and I would like to add a timestamp for every backup to the name of the .Bak file.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?  This looks painfully simple with C#...

Comment: Truth is I don't know how to cut the query in half and add a Datetime. I' don't know if there is a query command for this.

Comment: This isn't a query - this is a string whose contents are a query.  You can do any kind of string concatenation, formatting, or whatever else you can think of to manipulate it.  You may want to look into `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formatting of string like:

```
string query = string.Format("BACKUP DATABASE DbName TO DISK = 'C:\\app\\dbName{0}.Bak' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'dbName', NAME = 'Full Backup of dbName';", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
string query = string.Format( "Backup Database DbName To Disk='C:\\BackUp" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".bak'");
```